# Does someone who masters the VPS host technology can deploy its NodeJS _ ReactJS app on all - or a great amount - of VPS host available online?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

I'm a newbie on app hosting. If I understand well, someone who masters the VPS host technology can deploy its NodeJS - ReactJS application on all - or a great amount - of VPS host available online ? I mean, does theses VPS host *can be, theorically,* reliable when it comes to serve and host 24/7 application in production ?

If anyone have an hint, would be great,

thanks

Comment: Would depend on the hosting company. Pick a reliable one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who knows if the VPS host is reliable - it's a company that has servers, and companies fudge things up sometimes. It depends on the host, and even then, it's very opinionated.

In regards to whether you can host your node.js application on almost any VPS - this is true. A VPS is simply a virtual machine on a company's servers that they rent out. Since node.js runs on most flavors of linux you could reliably install node.js and run your app on the VPS.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'I would avoid to sent my app on a no-compliant environment.' What are you looking for your VPS host to be compliant to?

edit: Theoretically, of course, yes they are reliable. The entire world runs on servers and virtual servers, there is no other way to host something besides a server or a virtual server. In reality - no, nothing is 100% reliable, and if you want the most availability and uptime you may want to deploy across multiple hosts and countries and look into high availability, depending on how critical uptime is to your application.

Also look for hosts with high SLAs (service level agreements). This is how much uptime they guarantee before they reimburse you - ex. Amazon EC2 VPS's guarantee a 99.99% percent uptime (4 minutes 23 seconds or less downtime per month) or will refund you 10-30% of your monthly price

Comment: I will edit my topic, I would just mean, if VPS can do the job theorically, so it seems that yes, that was my question so thanks, obviously on the field it necessary to check and probate the requirement of the different VPS  available.